# How to put loaded content into angular scope?

Tags: angularjs

I use angular directive for fancybox:

```
.directive('fancybox', function ($compile, $http) {
    return {
        scope: false,
        restrict: 'EA',

        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.openFancybox = function (href) {

            $http.get(href, {cache:false}).then(function(response) {
                if (response.status == 200) {

                    var template = angular.element(response.data);
                    var compiledTemplate = $compile(template);
                    compiledTemplate(scope);

                    $.fancybox.open({ content: template, type: 'html'});
                }
            });


            };
        }
    };
})
```

But loaded content does not use my controller $scope.
For example, in the controller, I specified **$scope.file**, and there is **ng-model="file"** in the loaded content, but it not bound to my controller object.

I tried to specify scope:true, it also did not help.

Comment: You are loading your content via jQuery not angular js so don't expect it to work. You may try to fix you code by using `$compile` service, but from your question I guess you are not advanced angular user - and using `$compile` would cause more trouble than it's worth. It will be better to find some angular friendly replacement of fancybox. Here example with compile service: http://gyf1.com/blog/2014/06/16/angularjs-fancybox/ Here is Angular UI library that provide message box functionality: https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Comment: I will check out your links, but can you tell me about compile - I already use it in the code, why it does not work as I expected?

Comment: Try change `open` to `open(template)`